# Where can one find the rich list of the BAT token?

Tags: basic-attention-token

Is there a rich list made for the BAT token?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/token/0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef#balances

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of largest holders [here](https://etherscan.io/token/0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef#balances).

There are a few things to note:

1. Many large holders separate their holdings into multiple accounts. This helps protect their privacy and allows them to spend tokens without all eyes being on them at all times.
2. The largest holder, `0x7c31560552170ce96c4a7b018e93cddc19dc61b6`, is sitting on 22.6857% of the tokens. This is the UGP (User Growth Pool), owned by the BAT team. These funds go towards user growth and awareness only and are not owned by an external entity.
3. The second largest holder, `0xfbb1b73c4f0bda4f67dca266ce6ef42f520fbb98`, is the Bittrex wallet, holding 9.9151% of tokens. These are all the tokens that are currently sitting on the Bittrex exchange.
4. Similarly, the third largest holder, `0xfe9e8709d3215310075d67e3ed32a380ccf451c8`, is Binance with 8.1300% of the tokens.